# Understanding Vuetify within and outside of v-stuff

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I am trying to learn Vuetify, and the documentation is great. But it is just **so different** from standard HTML / JS that there is still a lot of "missing" documentation.

Specifically, how should I mark up `<v-things>` versus `<normal HTML tags>`?

For example, if I add `dark` to `<v-things>`, then that HTML tag will have white text that stands out (against a dark background):

```html
<v-toolbar color="primary" dark>
```

The HTML tag above, **because it starts with `<v-...`**, can use the "magic words" `color` and `dark`.  This will make everything in that toolbar use my `"primary"` theme color for the background, and white for the text.

How would I do the same thing in a `<div>` or some other non-Vuetify-specific tag?

For instance,

```html
<div color="primary" dark>
```

will not work.  So, what should I do to accomplish this?  The following, which was my first guess, did not work:

```html
<div class="primary dark">
```

---

Two questions:

1. How would I accomplish the thing that I did with `<v-toolbar>`, but with `<div>` or any other *normal* HTML tag?
2. Should I avoid using normal HTML tags entirely?

Regarding (2) above: I had some text on a login page that would be empty until the user tries to log in. Then a `<div>` would be populated with a message from the server either saying "successful login" or "login failed".  I wanted to color these with the "success" or "error" color themes.  Should I not use a `<div>`?  How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are some questions being asked, so I'll try to explain everything.

#### What is v-*?

In vue.js, there are these things called [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

Components provide a way to separate your code into reusable pieces that you tie together in your application. They render common HTML tags (Vuetify also adds classes, for styling), but in Vue you can call them whatever you want.

#### What is vuetify?

Vuetify is a component library, and these `v-things` are just components that you can use, each one with a job to accomplish.

`dark`, for instance, is what is called a [`prop` or `property`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) that you can pass to components from the parent instance/component. Props can only be used in components, and not in normal HTML elements, like `<div>`.

#### Now, for question number 1:

If you want to have a `div` with white text and primary background in Vuetify, you would use classes instead of props. [Here's the documentation for Vuetify's color system](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#classes).

So, basically you get this example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main class="pa-5">
        <div class="pa-4 primary white--text">
          I'm a blue div with white text!
        </div>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### Question number 2:

In most cases you'll want to use the components provided by Vuetify, but sometimes you can simply use classes instead to get the desired style.

You don't need to drop normal HTML at all, just use it as you see fit. You'll still need to use `<p>` for paragraphs and you can use `<strong>` for **bold text**.
But for common things such as buttons and menus, Vuetify provides those with a nice styling and all javascript functionality, so that's when you'd use the components instead of normal HTML.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Phiter!  Yes, I guess I should have explained the Vue + Vuetify landscape better... but you now did it for me.  I had actually tried `text--white`, not `white--text`.  I was so close!